# Doing $http.get with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

Im trying to do a $http.get with angular:

```
var monster_info = angular.element(this).find("img").attr("title");
                        $http.get("lib/terrain.php", {monster_data: monster_info}).success(function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        });
```

Here is my terrain.php:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $objData = json_decode($data);
    echo $objData->monster_data;
```

The only returns an empty string when using GET. But if I change to $http.post, it works perfect. How can I make it work with $http.get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this,**

> var monster_info = angular.element(this).find("img").attr("title");
>
> $http.get("lib/terrain.php", {
>
> ```
> params: { monster_data:monster_info}}).success(function(data) {
>
> console.log(data);
> ```
>
> });